# Magento About Page problem

Tags: topmenu

I followed a tutorial to create a about page.

I created firstly a subcategory about page and then a page "about page".

The about page is in top menu which is correct.

My problem is that the about page, shows also in the left menu, I want to remove it from there, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query, I can imagine that you are managing "**about page**" from a category.

If yes, then set value of **Is Anchor** attribute to **`No`** under **Display Settings** in category.

Please let me know if problem still exists.

Comment: Hello, thank's for your help,  category about page , display settings-- anchor "no".

Comment: but the problem still exists

Comment: Are you using any custom theme?

Comment: metro shop theme

Comment: Sorry, this theme has no preview active. Please let me know whether it has any menu manager module and left menu manager?

Comment: i clould not find any manager...

Comment: Ok, have you cleared Magento cache and done reindexing after making changes in Is Anchor attribute?

Comment: yes, all done, problem still exists